# Problem building docker with numpy and pandas over arm64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, docker, arm64

I'm trying to build a docker image with docker-compose in my ARM64 rasperry pi but it seems to be imposible.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3-dev 

RUN apt-get -y install python3-numpy
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pandas

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "app.py"]
```

It seems to be OK, but when app.py is run, it gives an error: "Module numpy not found", and the same for pandas module.

If I try to install numpy and pandas using pip:

```
RUN pip install numpy pandas
```

It gives me an error or, more usually, the raspberry just gets frozen and I have to unplug it to recover.

I have tried with different versions of python for the source image and also using several ubuntu images and installing python.

Any idea of how can I install numpy and pandas in docker for my raspberry pi (ARM64)?

Thanks

Comment: `dpkg -L python3-numpy` to see if numpy was in in your python3 path.

Comment: It's a complex environment. Bot sure, try to add command `RUN pip3 install -U numpy`.

Comment: Are you sure your Raspberry Pi is ARM64? It is farily typical for Raspberry Pi using Raspbian to be a 32 bits OS. Anyways, that's not really the point. `pip install` works for me, but expect to wait minimum half an hour (even for a Raspberry Pi 3!) and I am not sure if adding pandas will increase that to multiple hours. If you use a good enough power supply and give enough time, `pip` should eventually end.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'm using a 64bit OS on the Raspberry. Anyway, installing pandas and numpy with pip takes so long that most of times the raspberrys dies.  I'll answer my own question with a solution I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems seems to be with the python version. I'm using a python3.6 docker image but, both python3-numpy and python3-pandas packages require python3.5, so when those packages are installed a new version of python is also installed. This is why when I'm trying to import those modules the python interpreter can't found them, because they are installed for another python version.

Finaly I solved it using a generic docker debian image and installing python3.5 myself instead of using a python docker image.

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3.5 libblas3 libc6 liblapack3 gcc python3-dev python3-pip cython3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-numpy python3-sklearn
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pandas

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/

RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**(Disclaimer: The Raspberry Pi 3 B+ is probably too slow to install big dependecies like numpy)**

This Dockerfile worked for me on the Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Software-Version: *Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7+* (Consider updating it)

```
FROM python:3.9-buster

WORKDIR /

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I am not sure, but I think it helped also to clean docker i.e. remove all images and containers with the following commands:

**Warning: This commands deletes all images and containers!**

```
$ docker container prune
$ docker image prune -a
```

Or reset Docker completely (deletes also volumes and networks):

```
$ docker system prune --volumes
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend to create `requirements.txt` file.
Inside you can declare packets to install.

The `Dockerfile':

```
FROM python

COPY app.py /workdir/
COPY requirements.txt /workdir/

WORKDIR /workdir

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

CMD python app.py
```

---

edit

I create `Dockerfile` which import pandas lib and then checking if it work:

```
cat Dockerfile 
FROM python

COPY app.py /workdir/

WORKDIR /workdir

RUN python -m pip install pandas

CMD python app.py
```

Comment: In fact, in my actual dockerfile I am using a requirements.txt file. I didn't use it in the question for clarity purposes. Anyway, it doesn´t change anything. "Pip install" (using requirements file or not) is not working.